# I must be treated different if I don't have childrens with my husband?

Tags: hadith, women

I have a muslim husband and me I am not. When he asked me for marriage I told him that I will not make him chidrens because I am much older than him and the nature say it's word. I had before children's with my previous husband. My question is: should I be treated different from the womans who have children's with their husband from the point of view of food, clothes or other rights of muslims wifes? Should I be forced to give 50% of the expenses in the house because I don't have children's?

Comment: Muhammad pbuh had many wives and many of them had not children, and muhammad Pbuh gave them equal right

Answer (score 2):

No, every wife should be taken care of and treated kindly it doesn’t matter whether she has kids with her husband or not. Some of prophet Muhammad’s (pbuh) wives had kids from their previous marriages and he did his best on treating them all equally. Allah knows best.

Answer (score 1):

In Islam, husbands are responsible for their wives and the lady of the house is not obligated to contribute to the earnings. Her responsibilities for which she will be questioned is did she keep herself chaste from others, did she look after the house well and did she bring up the children to be good Muslims.

***In short, you should NOT be forced to give 50% of the expenses in the house because you are not a mother*** (yet).

But please note Islam lays a great emphasis on family and children are the bond that generally keeps a family united. Moreover, children are a source of 'Sawab e Jariya' for the parents.

Unless, you have a medical reason, I recommend you reanalyze your views on not having a child.